# defaultdict adding more values to a key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list:

```
('1', ['/home/test34', '/home/test33'])
```

I need to append the list as follows (`x` is the timestamp ):

```
('1', ['/home/test34',x], ['/home/test33',x])
```

I was using this, `mylist` is a `defaultdict`:

```
mylist[name].append(dirpath)
mylist[name].append(creation_time)
```

When I use the above it is giving the following:

```
('1', ['/home/test34',x, '/home/test33',x])
```

I need to find a easy way to sort the list by creation date (timestamp `x`).
What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question by giving examples of input-output? Looking at the answers, I think this is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

in Python3.5+, you can also use extended iterable unpacking

```
lst = [('1', ['/home/test34', '/home/test33']), ...]

result = [(a, *[(path, timestamp) for path in b]) for a, b in lst]
# [('1', ('/home/test34', 'some timestamp'), ('/home/test33', 'some timestamp')), ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert pairs of `(timestamp, path)` instead of separate objects, you can then use the `tuple` ordering to sort your new list. Optionally, you can remove the timestamps after sorting.

Here I do not know what you timestamps input looks like, so I replaced them with integers.

```
lst = ['/home/test34', 2], ['/home/test33', 1], ['/home/test35', 3]

def sorted_by_timestamp(lst):
    timestamp_path = sorted((timestamp, path) for path, timestamp in lst)

    return [timestamp for _, timestamp in timestamp_path]

print(sorted_by_timestamp(lst)) # ['/home/test33', '/home/test34', '/home/test35']
```